# Symfony configurable entity path through yaml?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, yaml

I've made a basic bundle. In my bundle, one of my Doctrine entities is *required* to be extended, so i'll need to know how to load the entity the user of my bundle created.

I see other bundles doing things such as:

```
my_bundle:
    product_class: Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Product
```

Then doing something similar to:

```
$product = $this->container->get( 'my_bundle.product_manager' ); // somehow uses the yaml value for my_bundle.product_class
$product->setName( 'test' );
$product->save( );
```

It seems like these bundles are converting the YAML somehow to a usable doctrine entitiy. How are they doing this and the best approach to it?

Comment: Why dont you use the class in your controller: "use Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Product" So that you can create it: "$product = new Product()"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using service factories from Symfony's documentation. I passed the user's parameters into the factory and it worked fine as a repository.